# Cordova geolocation.getCurrentPosition Works in Monaca iPhone Debugger But Not With Built iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, geolocation, monaca

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition Cordova API method works with the Monaca Debugger/ App Emulator installed on my iPhone, but freezes in the built iOS version on the same phone.

I added the following to the config.xml but it didn't fix the problem.

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to reproduce your problem. Unfortunately you posted less information. So i set up a new cordova project:

1. `cordova create geolocationTest com.example.com geolocationTest`
2. `cd geolocationTest`
3. `cordova platform add ios`
4. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`
5. `cordova build`

Then i moved into that folder and edited the index.html. I added this code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("navigator.geolocation works well");
}
```

After that i added the Example from the Geolocation-Plugin Documentation:

```
// onSuccess Callback
// This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
// current GPS coordinates
//
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

That all worked fine for me. So the problem has to be anywhere in your code. You should provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the problem. iOS8 requires the following in the app plist:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

and locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization or locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization needs to be called before navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is called.
The following explains the change with iOS8: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

The current problem I'm having now is successfully invoking locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization or locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization in the Monaca environment.